# Does a sqlcode value other than zero always indicate an error condition in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlcode

if sqlcode is not 0 (in oracle plsql)  then always throw an exception?

makes sense to ask for SQLCODE if not is an exepcion.
Example:

```
if (sqlcode = 0) ...
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: A question mark alone doesn't make a sentence a question.

Comment: What is the point of doing if (sqlcode <> 0), the ... else... outside the block of excepcion

Comment: if sqlcode is not 0 then always throw an exception?

Answer (score 4):

IF you are asking if you should always throw an exception if SQLCODE is not zero, not always.

Here is a [list of some SQLCodes](http://www.caliberdt.com/tips/sqlcode.htm).  As you can see, some SQLCodes ( such as 100 ) do not necessarily mean that there is an error.

Hope this helps

Comment: oracle is inconsistent. As I understand sqlcode only makes sense inside an exception handler. But  not always  throw an exception if sqlcode is not zero.

Comment: Yes.  I would only look at the SQLCODE in the context of an exception handler.  It can, however, be useful when tracing down bugs in code.  Since I didn't know in what context to take your question, I was trying to be as generic as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're mixing error checking and exception handling.  [SQLCODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/sqlcode_function.htm#i36302), by definition, only makes sense inside an exception handler.

Raising exceptions happens automatically.  Unless your code is catching exceptions and returning them instead of re-raising them.  Which kind of ruins
the whole point of exception handling.